# Product compare plugin not working

Tags: magento2, plugin, around-plugin

Here is the plugin i created for limiting 3 products can be added into comparison. But it not loading, add one know what is the problem?

etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\Compare\Add">
        <plugin name="LimitToCompareProducts"
                type="Custom\TestCompare\Plugin\LimitToCompareProducts"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * 
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Custom_TestCompare" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

Plugin/LimitToCompareProducts.php

```
<?php

namespace Custom\TestCompare\Plugin;

    use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
    use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare;
    
    class LimitToCompareProducts
    {
        const LIMIT_TO_COMPARE_PRODUCTS = 3;
    
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
         */
        protected $messageManager;
    
        /**
         * @var RedirectFactory
         */
        protected $resultRedirectFactory;
    
        /** @var Compare */
        protected $helper;
    
        /**
         * RestrictCustomerEmail constructor.
         * @param Compare $helper
         * @param RedirectFactory $redirectFactory
         * @param ManagerInterface $messageManager
         */
        public function __construct(
            RedirectFactory $redirectFactory,
            Compare $helper,
            ManagerInterface $messageManager
        )
        {
            $this->helper = $helper;
            $this->resultRedirectFactory = $redirectFactory;
            $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        }
    
        public function aroundExecute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\Compare\Add $subject,
            \Closure $proceed
        ){
    
            $count = $this->helper->getItemCount();
            if($count > self::LIMIT_TO_COMPARE_PRODUCTS) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                    'You can add the compared products under 3 item(s)'
                );
    
                /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
                $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                return $resultRedirect->setRefererOrBaseUrl();
            }
    
            return $proceed();
        }
    }
```

registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Custom_TestCompare',
    __DIR__
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is add a dependency on `Magento_Catalog` which should change the load order of the modules so that yours loads after `Magento_Catalog`:

In etc/module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Custom_TestCompare" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        <sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Then run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` so that your module load order changes in `app/etc/config.php`.

Outside of that, did you do the following?

- Verify that your module is enabled in `app/etc/config.php` (should see `Custom_TestCompare => 1` in the module list)
- Verify the path to the module is `app/code/Custom/TestCompare`

### Compare Limit Logic

Also noticed that you check if `$count > 3`. Should it be `$count >= 3` to prevent a customer from being allowed to add 4 items before your plugin limits?